# pandas: how to create a single date column from columns containing year, month, and day?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I hava a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
year month day
2019     1  29
2019     1  30
2019     1  31
2019     2   1
```

I'd like to create a date column with the proper data type e.g.:

```
year month day date
2019     1  29 2019-01-29
2019     1  30 2019-01-30
2019     1  31 2019-01-31
2019     2   1 2019-02-01
```

I know in Python, I can create a date from its year/month/day components like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(year=2019, month=1, day=29)
datetime.date(2019, 1, 29)
```

How can I apply that to all the rows in my dataframe to create a date column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method also works;

```
df['combined'] = pd.to_datetime([f'{y}-{m}-{d}' for y, m, d in zip(df.year, df.month, df.day)])
```

EDIT 2019-11-17 to respond to @HenryHenrinson

Thank you for your comments. I did go back and check performance to see if you are correct.

I created a dataframe of days from 1980-01-01 to 2019-01-01.

```
df.head()

   year  month  day
0  1980      1    1
1  1980      1    2
2  1980      1    3
3  1980      1    4
4  1980      1    5

print(df.info())

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 14246 entries, 0 to 14245
Data columns (total 3 columns):
year     14246 non-null int64
month    14246 non-null int64
day      14246 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(3)
memory usage: 334.0 KB
None
```

Testing the iterrows solution below:

```
%timeit [datetime.date(year=x[1].year, month=x[1].month, day=x[1].day) for x in df.iterrows()]

results in: 
1.23 s ± 30.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Testing my solution:

```
%timeit pd.Series(pd.to_datetime([f'{y}-{m}-{d}' for y, m, d in zip(df.year, df.month, df.day)]))

results in: 
9.9 ms ± 159 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And testing the solution of the great and powerful @wenyoben...

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df)

results in: 
8.81 ms ± 206 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

@wenyoben solution is fastest and most elegant and should be the preferred answer.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that it returns a column of strings, not datetime-like objects.

Comment: @Paul H Could you clarify your statement? It's showing up as datetime64 in my code.  ------> combined    4 non-null datetime64[ns]

Comment: Whoops, I misread it. ignore me

Comment: This is bad because it requires you to build and parse strings which is remarkably inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way of doing it

```
df1['date'] = [datetime.date(year=x[1].year, month=x[1].month, day=x[1].day) for x in df1.iterrows()]
```

Output:

```
   year  month  day        date
0  2019      1   29  2019-01-29
1  2019      1   30  2019-01-30
2  2019      1   31  2019-01-31
3  2019      2    1  2019-02-01
```

Comment: oh, it's already been answered :(

Comment: you don't need to iterate with pandas dataframes like this

Comment: magic here try `pd.to_datetime(df)`

Comment: @Wen-Ben beautiful, once again, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Your solution is better, as it does not require building strings and then using pd.to_datetime magic. People complain when you "iterate" with pandas, but are ok with building a billion strings to just to parse some dates